# git push to github ask password for another user

Tags: git, ssh, github

I configured git and my github account following the tutorials in the github web site. Now, I tried to push my files into github with `git push -u origin master` but it ask my for some password

```
myunixuseraccount@gitub.com's password
```

Please note two things: first, my github account is not `myunixuseraccount`, second, note the typo in 'gitub.com' (yes, he asks for gitub, not github).

I believe that something is not well configured, but I can't figured what. I looked at git/config but in no place it mentions that user.

Any help will be really appreciate

Comment: How did you clone the repo? Did you copy/paste?

Comment: No, I didn't clone any report, I tested with a test project. I created, commit and then git push -u origin master

Answer (score 1):

In `.git/config`, your remote url should be something like `git@github.com:yourgithubuser/repo.git`

If you use https instead of private keys to push to github, replace the url with the https url on your github page for that repository.

Comment: Yes, I did this but with https doesn't connect at all. I looked at other stackoverflow answer and they said to change https to ssh